# Excel: How to Compare Values in a row based on a specific value in a different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for an excel formula that will allow me to compare multiple values in different rows based on the value in the cell against each other.
I need the formula to look at for all the cells in column C, find the same ones, and compare the value in column B for all the same values in column C.
For example, I need the formula to look find that there are 6 same values that are Account 3 and compare the column B value and give me false if the value in column B are not the same.

Hope this made sense. I've been trying different if formulas to no avail. Thank you!

[Here is an image of this set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV9bw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Someone may come up with a formula for this, but the first thing that came to mind was creating a pivot table from your data, and then using a formula against the pivot results.

Here, we created a pivot table on your data, and during the pivot creation, check the box for "add this data to the data model". In the pivot design, the rows is Account and the values is Count of Type. Then right-click on any of the Count of Type rows that has a value, and select "Value Field Settings". Scroll down and select "Distinct Count". Since we added the data to the data model, then Distinct Count is an option.

Then Column D can have your True/False formula of:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(C2,H:I,2)>1,"False","True")
```

This formula will show FALSE if the account has more than one distinct type, else TRUE.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I best understand your question, a possible formula approach can be as follows.

Refer the sample data screenshot below.

[image]

**First get list of Unique values from Col C Account.**

In E2 put following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. This step is required. The array formula will be automatically enclosed in curly braces. Drag it down until you get blank. Now this will create a unique list. Header row required in this case for formula to work correctly.

If you have Office 2021 or 365 you may directly use UNIQUE function.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$16,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$C$2:$C$16),0)),"")
```

**Now apply the criteria**

In F2 put the following formula.

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$16,E2)=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$16,E2,$B$2:$B$16,INDEX($B$2:$B$16,MATCH(E2,$C$2:$C$16,0)))
```

Drag it down as required.

**In case you just want Col D to show the Status for each Account in Col C.**

Use the following formula in D2 and drag it down as required.

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$16,C2)=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$16,C2,$B$2:$B$16,INDEX($B$2:$B$16,MATCH(C2,$C$2:$C$16,0)))
```

[image]